# Are there any methods in Selenium for waiting until a page is fully loaded?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find a method that waits when all elements on the page will be fully loaded.

I found out a good idea and it is working very well:

```
def waiting_new_page(link: WebElement) -> None:
    waiting_update = True
    while waiting_update:
        try:
            link.find_element(By.ID, "does not matter")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            sleep(1)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            waiting_update = False

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("window-size=800,600")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
link = browser.find_element(
    By.NAME,
    "thePage:SiteTemplate:theForm:Continue"
)
link.click()
waiting_new_page(link)
```

Are there any ready methods in Selenium to wait until page is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebDriverWait` function in Selenium

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body')))
```

Or instead of `body` you can put your selector you want wait until to load.

Comment: I tried this method but it does not work when I click to the button on a web page to open another. Because there is a selector 'body'  in `browser` before I click the button.